# Java generic type conversion like <String, String> to <Object, Object>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Is there a way in java to convert type

from : `<Object, Object>`

to : `<String, String>`

or

from : `<String, String>`

to : `<Object, Object>`

I have it between `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>` and `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>`

Comment: Why not just do a type cast?

Comment: @kaya3 It is a compile error to do a explicit type casting between generic <Object> and <String>

Comment: What is the compiler error? You need to include all relevant information like this in your question. Please see [ask].

Comment: do you want a brutal solution - one that just gets the cast done wihtout any safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use intermediate raw type. Here's an example for `Object` to `String` conversion. Reverse conversion will look identical.

```
static ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> stringFactoryToObjectFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> stringFactory) {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory rawTypeFactory = stringFactory;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> objectFactory = rawTypeFactory;
    return objectFactory;
}
```

Of course it violates type safety and `ClassCastException` will occur at runtime, if those factories will use different types.